# How to choose the "family" on gbm.step?

Tags: r, tree, gbm, dismo

my dependent variable is continuous and not normal but I'm not sure which family to choose ... when I run the analysis, this message appears:

restart model with a smaller learning rate or smaller step size ...
it is the first time that I do this analysis and any help would be very welcome. thanks

```
ina <- gbm.step(data=bonaci, gbm.x = 10:33, gbm.y = 9, 
                family = "gaussian", tree.complexity = 5, 
                learning.rate = 0.01, bag.fraction = 0.5)
```

Comment: Hi @Ina, how big is the dataset, and can you do a histogram on the dependent variable? You can go a bit lower on the learning but it will take longer

Comment: Hi @StupidWolf... in fact, the dataset is not that big. I have 187 samples for the dependent variable. But I already made a log for this variable to be able to fit the conditions of normality of the gaussian family... But I have others struggles with this analysis. If you could help me, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Not anymore. My current problem is to break the y-axis scale of one of my plotted variables. Specifically the depth... If you can take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62492653/gbm-plot-function-how-can-i-insert-a-scale-break-in-one-of-the-plot-charts